# Passing multi word variable as default input to html textbox

Tags: html, textbox

I am passing a Python variable (`x`) storing a multi word value `x="ABC DEF"`, to an html textbox as the default value. In the page, only the first word 'ABC' is displayed in the text box as the default value.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<td width="15%" bgcolor="WHITE" align="Left">
  <input type="text" name=""",input_value,""" value=""",x,""" selected="selected">
</td>
```

How can I display the value 'ABC DEF' as default value in the text box?

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you the following bypass, since i'm no python expert, but it should work:
1. replace the space with some sign that there is no way you'll ever write on you own. for example: "!#R%33" (just an example yeah?. you can replace space with: "_" if it is ok with you).

2. capture that string you sent via php on server side and use str_replace from that sign to space again, and walla.. write the value inside the html.

Once again, that is a workaround. hope the idea would help.

Comment: No, the issue is other way round. In server, I have a value 'ABC DEF'. I am fetching it and I want to display it as 'ABC DEF' in text box for editing. But it is displaying as 'ABC'. The rest part is not displayed. I do not want to display it as 'ABC_DEF'. I want to display the data in the same way as it is in the server.

Comment: @S.Banerjee so why not do the solution i've suggest on the server side? and convert back on python?. Again, not the most beautiful but would work :)